# trouble using a String variable as part of an 'if' condition

Tags: java, html, jsp

I need to use the 'checked' option in a radio button, but I want to use it dynamically. That is, either the right or the left button is pre-checked based on data from a database and the user can choose to accept or change it. To do this, I need the String "checked" as part of my radio button tag. I created two variables, chekR and chekL, with the plan that one of them would evaluate to "" while the other would evaluate to " checked". However, my IF condition fails to do the job. The value Right or Left comes from a form, and I tried printing it, which works fine, but the actual comparison is failing.

The variable passed from the form is stored as String D. If I try evaluating (D == "Right"), it returns a false every time. I tried two IFs (see code), I tried IF-ELSE, but no success.

```
String chekR = "";
String chekL = "";
if(D == "Left") { chekL = " checked";}
if(D == "Right") { chekR = " checked";}
<form action = update3.jsp><br>
<input type="radio" name="PtEye" value="Right" <%=chekR%>>Right
<input type="radio" name="PtEye" value="Left" <%=chekL%> required>Left
<br><input type="submit" value="Confirm"><input type="reset" value="Restore to original"></form>
```

I need the expression <%=chekL%> to produce either a blank or the word checked, depending upon the value of D.

Comment: In Java `==` compares object reference, not value. What you want when comparing strings, is the `String.equals(String)` method, which compares by value and not reference.

Comment: Yup. Spot on. That worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to the operator issue, did you write your java code inside <% %> block?

```html
<%
String chekR = "";
String chekL = "";
if(D == "Left") { chekL = " checked";}
if(D == "Right") { chekR = " checked";}
%>
```

Comment: Yes. That I did. But I did not include it in the code snippet I posted. Still, sometimes it's the littlest things that get you. :)